# Opencv make Image with gray mask

Tags: python, opencv

This has puzzled me for some time.
What I want to do is to be able to display my end result of a mask that has been blurred in OpenCV (using Python).

As the mask is no longer binary cv2.bitwise_and will not do a proppe job.
As the mask and image are in np.uint8, cv2.multiply(img, mask) will saturate and the scale parameter is added after the multiplication (unless I change to float and go back..)
cv2.subtract and cv2.min will not scale the values in the gray zone in the propper way either.

Any suggestions on the smartes way of doing this?

Comment: I think I figured it out but using PILLOW, PIL.Image.composite(img,img_bg,mask). I do though need to rearrange the channels and formating using PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))